# Is there a Thread Pool for Silverlight with a maximum number of threads?

Tags: c#, silverlight, threadpool, system.reactive

I have created a renderer in Silverlight/C#. Currently I'm using `System.Threading.ThreadPool` to schedule rendering of tiles in parallel. This works well right now, but I would like to limit the number of threads used.

Since this runs on Silverlight there are a couple of restrictions:

- If I call `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` the application crashes [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
- There is no Task Parallel Library

I see a few options:

- Find an OSS/third party Thread Pool
- Implement my own Thread Pool (I'd rather not)
- Use Rx (which I do in other places)

Are there any tested alternative Thread Pools that work with Silverlight out there?

Or can anyone come up with a Rx expression that spawns a limited number of threads and queue work on these?

Comment: Why do you want to change the number of threads. To use the thread pool, your tasks should not run for a long time. So taking the fact, that it is already set to the number of cores, into account, it must be pretty efficient. Have you tried your code in a wpf application and confirmed that application works more efficiently with the number you set?

Comment: I have not tested with a WPF application and I'm not sure that it will be more efficient. I want to try this to see if it is more efficient and I want to be able to do this for debugging and understanding any synchronization issues.

Comment: It is hard to debug multithreaded applications and believe me you will not see much synchronization issues as the program hits the breakpoints and pauses itself.You need a profiler for this. Look at [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222826/profiling-net-thread-contention)

Comment: Yes, of course.. Debugging and understanding synchronization issues are two separate needs that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rx, check out:

https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ObservableAsyncMRUCache.cs

*(Copying this one file into your app should be pretty easy, just nuke the this.Log() lines and the IEnableLogger interface)*

Using it is pretty easy, just change your SelectMany to CachedSelectMany:

```
someArray.ToObservable()
    .CachedSelectMany(webService)
    .Subscribe(x => /* do stuff */);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Rx then it seems like you could quite easily write your own implementation of IScheduler. This could just apply a simple semaphore and then pass the work on to the ThreadPool. With this approach you get to leaverage the ThreadPool, allow for testing as you are coding against an interface and you will also have good seams for testing.

Further more, as you have written this yourself, you could actually use a small-ish (<10)set of Threads that you manage yourself (instead of the threadpool)so you can avoid ThreadPool starvation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ami Bar's [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx).  It's got a ton of features missing from the default .NET threadpool, allows you to set a MaxThreads property per threadpool instance, and supports Silverlight.